# Web view on lock screen? (to simulate incoming calls)

Tags: android, ios, cordova, meteor, cordova-plugins

I need to build a functionality that at certain scheduled times calls the user and if the user accepts the call, plays something in the phone's speaker. Basically what I need is an incoming call screen e.g. the one Skype has that comes up even when the phone is locked. It doesn't have to be a real phone call of course.

I've looked around to try to put together the pieces in meteor js and cordova.

To allow background scheduling I could use these two:

- Background mode Plugin:
  https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode
- Power Management Plugin https://github.com/boltex/cordova-plugin-powermanagement

To play the sound use howler.js: http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/104/howler.js-Modern-Web-Audio-Javascript-Library

However I'm not sure how to wake the phone and show the incoming call screen. I haven't seen any existing plugin for this.

Is it possible to put a web view on the lock screen? I need this on both iOS and Android.